# How to differentiate interpretively similar sections in Satie's Gnossienne #1

Tags: theory, technique, practice, analysis, interpretation

I’m learning Gnossienne #1 by Erik Satie. Earlier the composer instructs ‘Du bout de la pensée’ which I have no problem performing. The problem occurs when I reach the end of the piece with the directions ‘Sur la langue’. I can’t seem to get the music from *the tip of my thoughts* to *the tip of my tongue*. I always just wind up playing the ‘Sur la langue’ part with the same interpretation as the ‘Du bout de la pensée’ part, even though the notes are completely different.

Has anyone else had this problem when learning this piece? Is there an exercise that might help with this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do the written instructions in Satie's 1ère Gnossienne mean?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/95048/what-do-the-written-instructions-in-saties-1%c3%a8re-gnossienne-mean)

Comment: FYI: I've added an additional answer more directly addressing your question to the linked duplicate.

Comment: Hi Aaron, although I appreciate your input, you have not answered my question. You see, I do not require a translation of the composer’s instructions from French to English. My problem is more musical than linguistic. When I play the ending be itself, I have no problem playing Sur la langue. It’s when I play the entire piece  from the beginning that I get into trouble and slip right back into’Du bout de la pensée’!! It’s strange the notes are different. So thank you. Hopefully there’s a musician out there who understands this composer’s music. Vous avez manqué Le point

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. You're not asking how to interpret it; you're asking how to practice keeping the 'Sur la langue' section distinct from the 'Du bout de la pensée' section, yes?

Comment: Exactly!! I’m sure you’ll agree that music theory can never be precise. Music Theory is merely a phenomenal interpretation of the thing itself. There are no final solutions to the problem of understanding music, only more questions. I’ve been learning this price for nearly 15 years and I still don’t feel I know it.I appreciate the complexity of the question. But for musicians this is the nature of consciousness. I genuinely would welcome any feedback on this problem.

Comment: @4Erik Entertain this question: how would you describe the difference in others' performances that you've heard? I imagine, from your question, that you believe one's interpretation should be organically personal, and maybe are of the camp that resists listening to recordings lest it over-inform one's own interpretation. But assuming that the ultimate aim is communication to a listener, not just the performer's own experience (not always a given assumption), then any interpretive difference that is not conveyed is ineffective. So as a listener, how are you affected by these sections?

Comment: Satie's written instructions in all of his music are deliberately vague.  There isn't necessarily any one "correct" way to interpret them.  It's left to each individual performer to decide how exactly to read it.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I made the same mistake in understanding the question: it's not about how to interpret; rather, it's about how to practice the piece. OP is having trouble keeping distinct the two sections mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

In my interpretation of the piece, there is an alternation between statements or questions and self-evaluations. The key to properly executing the *du bout de la pensée* and *sur la langue* sections is in recognizing that *du bout de la pensée* is about considering the meaning of a statement, while *sur la langue* is about recognizing my failure to understand.

The practice technique for this is analysis. **Once the analysis is linked to the emotion, the execution takes care of itself.**

## The source(s) of the problem: similarities

There are two major issues that interfere with changing from *du bout de la pensée* to *sur la langue*

- The interpretations are very similar. Both are about searching internally regarding some thought. Both involve a stretching of the time and a sense that one is physically *reaching* a great distance or with intense effort for each note or chord.
- In both cases, the immediately preceding note material is identical.

These similarities of feeling, execution, and context make them closely associated within oneself, thus it's very easy to confuse one with the other on a felt level and, consequently, at the execution level. In this *du bout de la pensée* has the advantage, because it comes first.

## The solution

Because the problem lies in similarity, the solution lies in understanding the differences at both the felt and analytical levels.

I'll address these from the top down.

### The "story" of the piece

The starting point is having a large-scale context in which to place the individual sections. Here's my "story" for this piece. My intention here is to illustrate a method, not to assign an interpretation.

#### The big picture

"I have some ideas that initially I'm quite proud of, but on deeper examination I'm increasingly less certain of their value and suffer a crisis of confidence. In the end, it seems I've found validity, but ultimately it eludes me."

The large-scale structure is an alternation between a statement or question followed by self-evaluation.

The self-evaluation is always represented by the figure shown below, which is always played twice.

[image: "Self-evaluation" figure]
(IMAGE SOURCE: [IMSLP](https://imslp.eu/files/imglnks/euimg/c/cd/IMSLP237520-PMLP07506-Satie,_Erik-Klavierwerke_Peters_Klemm_Band_1_04_Gnossiennes_scan.pdf)) (NOTE: There is an error in the score excerpt, which was taken from the first edition. The fifth melodic half-note should be a quarter-note.)

#### The more detailed picture

The numbers refer to the left hand whole notes.
The boldface entries refer to the "self-evaluation" figure.

01–09: I make some statements.
10–18: I restate them to convince myself of their value.
**19–22: I am very proud of my statements. Watch me shine!**
**23–26: Yes, indeed. I feel quite good about myself.**
27–38: But, what does it really mean? Do I deserve this confidence?
**39–42: Yes, I do!**
**43–46: But do I really?**
47–54: I deeply ponder my statements and what I meant by them. (*du bout de la pensée*)
**55–58: I try to reassure myself.**
**59-62: I am not reassured.**
63–68: I am making an intense and wholehearted effort to search my inner self for answers.
69–74: I think I've just about got it worked out.
**75–78: I can see it! The light at the end of the tunnel! I can nearly grasp it.**
***79–81: I fail.*** (*sur la langue*)

- Notice that in the "self-evaluation" sections, the second statement of the figure is always more doubting that the first.

### The differences

| *du bout de la pensée* | *sur la langue* |
| --- | --- |
| Preceded by the end of a "self-evaluation" | Preceded by the beginning of a "self-evaluation" |
| Begins a "question" section | Concludes a "self-evaluation" section |
| Musical material is from the "A" section of the piece | Musical material is from the "B" section of the piece |
| Breaks its musical material up into smaller pieces | States its musical material in its entirety |
| Represents effort and hope | Represents failure and defeat |
| Represents an act of confidence (beginning to question anew) | Represents an act of self-doubt (the end of the piece) |

## Some practice tips

- Most of the practice is internal. Analyzing the differences in musical material and musical intention/feeling.
- Play the two segments back to back, alternating between them, in order to differentiate the felt, the analytical, and the physical execution of the two section.
- Work backwards, section by section, to discover any points where there's a discontinuity in your feeling. (The OP problem amounts to arriving at the end, rather than starting from the beginning. So practice arriving at the end.)

Comment: Just a minor correction: the fifth note of the melody in your score should be a quarter note, not a half note.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this makes sense, but to me the difference is that in the "Du bout de la pensée" (A) part you "lean back" and in the "Sur la langue" (B) part you "lean forward". I.e. in A you're holding back the main notes, and in B you're eager to get them out. Which translates to timing and attack I guess. In A I feel there should be more room behind the acciaccaturas, before their respective main notes and in B the main notes should come just a bit faster, giving a more rushed feeling.